# Seeking Alternatives to RefCell and Arena for Mutable Shared State in Single-Threaded Rust Application

Tags: rust

I'm developing a single-threaded Rust application and exploring data structure options for managing mutable shared state. My requirements are challenging because I want to maintain the benefits of Rust's compile-time safety checks while avoiding runtime panics associated with RefCell. Here's the context and the specific issues I'm facing:

**Option 1:** Using an Arena: I considered using an arena for memory allocation, referencing data via indexes. However, this approach complicates my use case due to the need for mutable access to the data stored in the arena. The arena pattern requires exclusive access for insertions, which doesn't work well when I need to maintain references to elements within the data structure, particularly because some of the values are enums with variant-specific patterns.

**Option 2:** Reference Counting with Rc and Weak: This seems viable, but I'm concerned about mutability and the potential for runtime panics with RefCell. My goal is to avoid pushing too many checks to runtime to preserve Rust's compile-time guarantees.

**Current Workaround:** I've temporarily circumvented these issues by using a concurrent data structure, specifically crossbeam's SkipMap, instead of BTreeMap or HashMap. This solution works but is not ideal, as it introduces constraints (Send + 'static), and is tailored for concurrent scenarios, maybe introducing useless overhead in a single thread applications, like atomics, or epoch-based reclamation

```
pub struct Arena<T> {
    data: SkipMap<usize, T>,
    next_id: Cell<usize>,
}

impl<T: Send + 'static> Arena<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Arena<T> {
        Arena {
            data: Default::default(),
            next_id: Cell::new(1),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&self, value: T) -> usize {
        // IF, IN OTHER IMPLEMENTATIONS, I WOULD INSERT A REFCELL HERE WHILE HOLDING AN ALIASING BORROW TO AN ELEMENT, PROGRAM PANICS
        let id = self.next_id.get();
        self.next_id.set(id + 1);
        self.data.insert(id, value);
        id
    }

    pub fn get(&self, id: usize) -> Option<impl std::ops::Deref<Target = T> + '_> {
        struct Dummy<'a, K, V> (Entry<'a, K, V>);
        impl<'a, K, V> Deref for Dummy<'a, K, V> {
            type Target = V;
            fn deref(&self) -> &V {
                self.0.value()
            }
        }
        self.data.get(&id).map(|entry| Dummy(entry))
    }
}
```

Are there alternative strategies or data structures in Rust that can accommodate these requirements? How can I implement an arena that allows mutable access to its elements without exclusive borrowing or runtime checks introduced by RefCell?

I've experimented with various concurrent maps, including DashMap, in search of a suitable solution for my problem. However, I've found that SkipMap is the only one that closely meets my needs. My program encountered deadlocks while using DashMap, a problem stemming from its underlying locking mechanism. This issue mirrors the challenges I faced with other maps and is akin to the drawbacks of using `RefCell` (through `RwLock`/`Mutex`), where the risk shifts from panics to deadlocks. Consequently, I'm in search of a lock-free map that is optimized for a single-threaded environment.

Comment: I think you need to use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html directly.
This requires some care to do correctly. Are you sure you need interior mutability?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's hard to suggest alternatives, when we don't even know what the problem is in the first place. I do want to add, that if you're trying to force shared mutability into Rust, then it already sounds like you're doing something wrong. The issue can most likely be fixed by rethinking your approach. When working with threads, there's likely a better solution using [channels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html). However, again, we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: It's not clear what the alternate solution you apparently dislike is, and your idea has major issues, notably that Rust's stdlib containers are not stable (at least not the hash containers or the vector-ish collections, not sure about btrees) so any `insert` which needs to resize the backing array will invalidate all extant references into the collection.

Comment: The second problem is that rustc has no way to know statically that your `insert` is not replacing an entry to which you're also holding a reference, which is the second reason these are exclusive operations.

Comment: @Unlikus I need to modify the arena (like inserting into its backing HashMap) while holding references to its elements, which requires interior mutability. `RefCell` risks panics when simultaneously referencing and modifying an element. I need a reference to an element because it is an enum, then I'll take a reference to one of the variants. `UnsafeCell` could work but forces me to use `unsafe` code, which I prefer to avoid.

Comment: "avoiding runtime panics associated with RefCell". `RefCell` will only panic if you use it incorrectly. You probably try to reborrow something whilst holding old borrows.

Comment: @vallentin I'm looking for a way to maintain a valid alias to a value within an arena, even while inserting new values simultaneously, without relying on a SkipMap. The code is [here](https://github.com/leonardogiovannoni/LLVM-Example/tree/arena). There is some unsafe for Sync and Send, which are not used in practice and easily removable.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze sure, and my problem is unsuitable for RefCell, but is good with a concurrent data structure (which is too much)

Comment: The title should be reworded, it's a blatant request for recommendations which are explicitly [off-opic](/help/on-topic), please rephrase it so it's not a recommendation request.

Comment: The point of an arena is that it doesn't require exclusive access to insert, see e.g. [`typed-arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/latest/typed_arena/struct.Arena.html#method.alloc).

Comment: First prototype the code with `RefCell` and test extensively. If it panics, then you're doing something wrong and any "solution" without `RefCell` would be unsound. If it doesn't panic, then you can probably keep the `RefCell`, unless _measurements_ show that this causes a performance issue, in which case you can replace them with `UnsafeCell`.